# How Do I Get The Default/Welcome Page Of A SharePoint 2010 Site?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm new to SharePoint 2010 coding web parts. I'm trying to figure out how to get the landing page of a SharePoint site given the URL.

Ex. I give the function http://www.yahoo.com and I get http://www.yahoo.com/pages/default.aspx .

Here's the function so far:

```
private string GetSPSiteUrl(string u) {
    var siteurl = string.Empty;

    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(u)) {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb()) {
            siteurl = web.Url;
        }
    }

    return siteurl;
}
```

The function just returns what I give it now which is no use.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Perhaps the guidance in [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/2bf31aee-e513-42c1-8e57-b86c815d6e9e) thread would be of assistance.

Answer (score 8):

A simpler approach without having to click through.

This gives you the direct "WelcomePage" url:

```
web.RootFolder.WelcomePage
```

If you need the actual item:

```
SPListItem welcomePage = web.GetFile(web.RootFolder.WelcomePage).Item;
```

Answer (score 4):

To ensure that anonymous users can get it use:

```
public static string GetWelcomePageUrl(SPWeb web)
    {
        if (web.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.BrowseDirectories))
        {
            return web.RootFolder.WelcomePage;
        }
        string welcomePage = string.Empty;
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
        {
            using (SPSite sPSite = new SPSite(web.Site.ID))
            using (SPWeb sPWeb = sPSite.OpenWeb(web.ID))
            {
                welcomePage = sPWeb.RootFolder.WelcomePage;
            }
        });
        return welcomePage;
    }
```